# Slow down in pandas operations in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have the following code that operates on a pandas dataframe. Repeating the operation makes the operation slower, geometrically.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def computation(_DF):
    for key in _DF.columns:
        _DF[f'{key}_1'] = _DF[f'{key}'].shift(1)
        _DF[f'{key}_diff'] = _DF[f'{key}'].diff()
    return _DF[-1:]


DF = pd.DataFrame()
for idx in range(5):
    DF[f'col_{idx}']=np.random.randint(10,size=10)
avg=0
for idx in range(10):
    startnow = time.time()
    result = computation(DF)
    avg+=time.time()-startnow
    print(f'Time: {time.time()-startnow}')
print(f'Average: {float(avg/10)}')
```

The result is:

```
Time: 0.0017206668853759766
Time: 0.0038039684295654297
Time: 0.008582830429077148
Time: 0.023931026458740234
Time: 0.03588294982910156
Time: 0.07429194450378418
Time: 0.15292000770568848
Time: 0.34928417205810547
Time: 0.880706787109375
Time: 2.5228471755981445
Average: 0.4053963661193848
```

The problem seems to be very basic and yet I cannot find the 'duh' solution. In the real code, computation only needs n rows from the dataframe (where n>>10) and only a few rows from the computation needs to be sent back. I have tried copying the result to a variable and deleting the _DF dataframe (setting it up for the garbage collector) but it makes no difference.

Thanks

Comment: Your DataFrame grows, approximately 3 times more columns, after each `computation` calls.

Comment: yes, and that is the problem. Holy smokes, an unintended consequence of ```
    for key in _DF.columns:
        _DF[f'{key}_1'] = _DF[f'{key}'].shift(1)
        _DF[f'{key}_diff'] = _DF[f'{key}'].diff()
    return _DF[-1:]
```
I don't miss working at the office, but i do miss hanging out with clever people. Next time you are in the Houston, Texas area @Quang-Hoang, food and beverages are on me